# What is the name of this tiny creature? It looks like a tiny piece of moving cotton?

Tags: entomology

[image]By chance, I saw this tiny insect on my bag a few days ago in Sydney. Am I the first person who has pinpointed this animal?! If not can you please let me know its name?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your image, it looks like it might be a woolly aphid. I just did a bit of cursory research, and it looks like they're often described as floating pieces of fluff, that seem to wander instead of directly heading somewhere. The fluff on their back is actually wax produced as a defense mechanism from predators and the like. I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Nice first answer. Take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to earn your first badge and [edit](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/74981/edit) your answer with a link to the species description or a picture to get another one! Have a nice stay!

Comment: Though I agree this is some species of woolly aphid, you need to update your answer as suggested by LinuxBlanket. Please provide links/citations to support your answer. Species ID answers require you to show support since incorrect identification is so prevalent...Providing a picture is also always helpful for species ID answers. thanks.